# How to swipe within a view controller within in an an array of strings?

Tags: ios, uitextview, swipe

My app has so many strings in an `NSArray` and the user usually can click on a button which is linked with an ib action to go either next or previous. When they click next or previous the text within a `TextView` changes to the next or previous string within the array. I want the user to be able to swipe within the `TextView` to go either next or previous. I've learned a little bit about how to recognize swipes but that requires a whole new `class` which inherits `UITextView` while my other class that contains the array and ib actions inherit a `UIViewcontroller`. I'm going to post what my code looks like and I just want to know how to connect either the swipe class or have within the action to recognize the swipe. Thanks for your time!

```
//DateIdeasViewController.m

    #import "DateIdeasViewController.h"

@interface DateIdeasViewController ()

@end

@implementation DateIdeasViewController
@synthesize labelsText;
@synthesize textView;
@synthesize adView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [adView setHidden:NO];
    NSLog(@"Showing");
}
- (void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [adView setHidden:YES];
    NSLog(@"Hidden");
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    adView.delegate = self;
    [adView setHidden:YES];

    titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              //Date ideas

       @"Some date ideas may be seasonal!",
               nil];
    step= 0;
    textView.text = [titles objectAtIndex:step];


    labelsText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d", step+1, titles.count];

}



-(IBAction) nextclicked:(id)sender{

    if (step<titles.count-1) {
        step++;
    }
    else
    {
        step= 0;
    }
    textView.text = [titles objectAtIndex:step];
    labelsText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d", step+1, titles.count];
}



-(IBAction) prevClicked:(id)sender{

    if (step>0) {
        step--;
    }
    else
    {
        step =titles.count-1;
    }
    textView.text = [titles objectAtIndex:step];
    labelsText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d", step+1, titles.count];
}


-(IBAction) randomClicked:(id)sender{

    step = 1+arc4random() %(titles.count-1);


    textView.text = [titles objectAtIndex:step];
    labelsText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d", step+1, titles.count];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(IBAction) favorite:(id)sender{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favorites"]];
    [array addObject:textView.text];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:array forKey:@"favorites"];


}

@end
```

SwipeableTextView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


#define kMinimumGestureLength   25
#define kMaximumVariance        5

typedef enum swipeDirection {
    kSwipeNone,
    kSwipeLeft,
    kSwipeRight
} tSwipeDirection;

@interface SwipeableTextView : UITextView {
    CGPoint gestureStartPoint;
    tSwipeDirection swipeDirection;
}
@end
```

SwipeableTextView.m

```
#import "SwipeableTextView.h"





@implementation SwipeableTextView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    swipeDirection = kSwipeNone;
    UITouch *touch =[touches anyObject];
    gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self];

    CGFloat deltaX = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.x - currentPosition.x);
    CGFloat deltaY = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.y - currentPosition.y);

    // Check if we already started a swipe in a particular direction
    // Don't let the user reverse once they get going
    if (deltaX >= kMinimumGestureLength && deltaY <= kMaximumVariance &&
        swipeDirection == kSwipeNone) {
        if (gestureStartPoint.x < currentPosition.x) {
            swipeDirection = kSwipeRight;
        }
        else {
            swipeDirection = kSwipeLeft;
        }
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (swipeDirection == kSwipeRight) {

    }
    else if (swipeDirection == kSwipeLeft) {
        NSLog(@"Swipe left");
    }
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
} 


@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to subclass a UITextView at all, just use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. In your view controller, you'll add something like this:

```
//Updated for both left and right swipes

//Create one gesture recognizer for the swipe left
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(actionToBePerformedOnSwipe:)];
swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.textView addGestureRecognizer:swipe];

//Then do the same for UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight
```

Your view controller will now be notified that the user swiped on the text view. Also, [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more) might help clarify gesture recognizers. **EDIT:** You can query the gesture recognizer (in the sender argument of the action method) for its direction by checking `((UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender).direction`.

However, if you want to go the UITextView route, you'll have to add a make the view controller the text view's delegate and add a method to represent the swipe. In your text view sub class's header, you'd add something like this:

```
@protocol SwipeableTextViewDelegate <UITextView>
-(void)textViewReceivedLeftSwipe;
-(void)textViewReceivedRightSwipe;

@end
```

The custom text view would call these methods on the delegate when the swipes were received, and the delegate (your view controller) would perform whatever action you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I took the top method and it works and thanks for the tutorial link. I just don't know how to recognize within the action if it's coming from the right or left within that method.